# What's meant by a thread-safe Ruby interpreter?

Tags: ruby, thread-safety, language-implementation

In a [2000 interview](http://linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2001/11/29/ruby.html) (that is, pre-YARV), Matz said

> Matz: I'd like to make it faster and more stable. I'm planning a full
>   rewrite of the interpreter for Ruby 2.0, code-named "Rite". It will be
>   smaller, easier to embed, thread-safe, and faster. It will use a
>   bytecode engine. It will probably take me years to implement, since
>   I'm pretty busy just maintaining the current version.

What was meant by "thread-safe" in this context? An interpreter that allowed you to use green threads? An interpreter that allowed you to use native threads? An interpreter that didn't have a global interpreter lock (GVL in YARV Ruby terminology)?

Comment: To *me* it means the lack of a "GIL" requirement. (But this supposes use of native threads, unless talking about just making core function re-entrant?)

Comment: Or since he's talking about embedding, perhaps he's talking about being able to use a ruby interpreter embedded in a regular c/c++ app from multiple threads?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment ruby's threading is less than ideal.  Ruby can use threading and the threading works fine, but because of its current threading mechanism, the long-and-short of it is that one interpreter can only use one CPU core at a time; there are also other potential issues.

If you want all the gory details, [This article](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/08/14/threads-in-ruby-enough-already/) covers it pretty well.